# Two Operations with the same name in the Service

Tags: web-services, wcf

Can I have two operations with the same name (but diferentt signature) in the same service?

Example:

```
[ServiceContract] 
public interface IMyService {
    [OperationContract]
    bool MyOperation(string target);

    [OperationContract]
    bool MyOperation(List<string> targets); }
```

I really need to support different signatures because I have several teams consuming my service and only one team needs the second signature (I don't want the rest of the team having to change their code).

Any thoughts?

Comment: Don't use value-type parameters, [use data contracts](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731138(v=vs.110).aspx). You can give your `MyOperationRequest` datacontract both properties (`string Target` and `List<string> Targets`) or something like that, and inspect which one is set. Or try using `List<string>` only and request at least one item is set.

Comment: I know about data contracts, but I'm doing code maintenance. The code is quite old and was developed by other teams. I cannot change the current interface to use data contracts (it would impact other teams) but need to support the new one (for the team requesting it). I suppose the only way is to name it differently. Thanks for your time :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you really cannot have the same named operations for the contract, but you can separate them between two contracts:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IMyService
{
    [OperationContract]
    bool MyOperation(string target);
}

[ServiceContract]
public interface IMyServiceV2
{
    [OperationContract]
    bool MyOperation(List<string> targets);
}


[ServiceContract]
public class MyService : IMyService, IMyServiceV2
{
    public bool MyOperation(string target)
    {
        /* your code*/
        return true;
    }

    public bool MyOperation(List<string> targets)
    {
        /* your code*/
        return true;
    }
}
```

And expose two endpoints:

```
<services>
  <service name="YourNamespace.MyService ">
    <endpoint
        address="http://localhost:8000/v1"
        binding="webHttpBinding" 
        contract="YourNamespace.IMyService" />

    <endpoint
        address="http://localhost:8000/v2"
        binding="webHttpBinding" 
        contract="YourNamespace.IMyServiceV2" />
  </service>
</services>
```

Or you can set Name param for OperationContract, but for SOA service it will have the same result as renaming function name.

Comment: Thanks. On my case, this is not an option but it can be a valid one for any other situation.

Comment: @jpaires What is your expected result? One endpooint (one address), but client1 has access to Method1, client2 has access to Method2?

Comment: The expected result is one endpoint and having clients using Method(list_of_params_1) or Method(list_of_params_2) depending on the given set of parameters. It's like method overloading for an operation.

Comment: @jpaires For your case it's only possible to use Name property for Operation contract attribute then (as described in the link provided by CodeCaster). As a result in SOAP message operation name will be replaced with one you set in Name property for operation.